# How to reload env's from within a running docker container

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-container

I checked the closed issue reported on github:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3285

But the solution doesn't works.

Comment: Can you detail what you trying to do and what you attempted?

Comment: Please add the exact steps that you have done and the way you did it. The link you provided doesn't give any idea of your issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add environment variables to an already running container.

From an environment-file, there's no way to do it currently, except removing the container and starting it again with the new env-file.

**For single variables you can use `docker exec CONTAINER_NAME export VARIABLE=VALUE`.**

The issue you linked to is about container configurations like cpu-limits and memory limits. Also you can change the restart policy with `docker update`.

Comment: Not able to override existing environment variable using export method

Comment: How are you checking if they got overrode? If you try to get the changed variables with `docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME bash`, you won't get them, as it acts similiar to an ssh session inside the container (new environment, old variables).
Try checking with `docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME env`